# Using a constant variable in C++

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ file in my C++ project in Visual Studio. 
The C++ file has a snippet wherein some applications are run using `system`

```
system("Files\\tx1");
system("Files\\tx2");
system("Files\\tx3");
system("Files\\tx4");
```

I want to replace the "Files" constant with some constant variable which can be changed at a single place. Something like what we wuld  do in C# with app.config files etc.
Directly hardcoding a constant is not a good practice. C++ project doesn't have settings file unlike C# projects. So, any suggestions what I should do in this case?

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a compile time approach (as with the `app.config` in C#) you can use defines.

conf.h

```
#define FILES "mypath"
```

impl.c

```
#include "conf.h"
...

system(FILES "tx1");
```

When you prefer a runtime approach, there are numerous formats/libraries for configuration files.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that app.config is runtime modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no similar mechanism to the app.config file you will have to spin your own. There are lots of frameworks out there for doing this.

One option is to use the [boost property tree library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree.html). This allows easy serialisation of configuration data to a variety of file formats.

However, you'd still have to create a global object for accessing these values.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write your own small settings parser which isn't that hard or use some premade library to read some kind of configuration file (e.g. you can use the Windows API to read/write ini files or you could use some kind of json/xml library).

I personally prefer using [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/) for stuff like this.

Comment: Why use WinAPI vs streams?  Why xml over text?

Comment: Depending on complexity and editability(sp?) it might be better or easier to do than reinventing the wheel (assuming that one path won't be everything to read).

Comment: oh, is there a Windows API to read/write ini files specifically?  Only one I know of was deprecated in Wind95 or so, but there might be others I'm not aware of.

Comment: `GetPrivateProfileString()` and `WritePrivateProfileString()` should still be available (they're kinda deprecated, but afaik still available due to compatibility reasons). I wouldn't use them for some public product, but should be fine for internal stuff and testing.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx "This function is provided **only** for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications. " (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class that did this for me:

```
class Path
{
private:
    static const std::string prefix_;

public:
    static std::string get(const std::string& file)
    {
        return prefix_ + '\\' + file;
    };
}; // eo class Path
```

.cpp

```
const std::string Path::prefix_ = "Files";
```

Now, it's easy to use everywhere else:

```
system(Path::get("tx1").c_str());
system(Path::get("tx2").c_str());
system(Path::get("tx3").c_str());
system(Path::get("tx4").c_str());
```

Comment: and how does it get initialized?

Comment: @MooingDuck, see the .cpp file where the prefix_ is given a name.  It's an entirely static class.

Answer (score -1):

instead of a constant, place an inline function that returns values appropriate, given minimally required data: for instance

```
inline const char *FileNum(int n) {
 static char buf[100];
 sprintf(buf, "Files\\txt%d", n);
 return buf;
}
```

and call

```
system(FileNum(1));
...
```